# How can I prevent that a webpage opened using Chrome Custom Tabs launches an App through deep linking?

Tags: android, deep-linking, chrome-custom-tabs

I am building an android app that on a given page allows the user to open a page on a website. I use chrome custom tabs for that.
The code is as follows:

```
String url = ¨https://website_containing_deep_link/¨;
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
```

On a particular website the page that is supposed to be rendered contains a deep link to launch a specific 3rd party app.

The above code launches the website but also launches the 3rd party app.
Can I configure custom tabs to not launch deep links?